# Extra menu_block showing on one page only

Tags: taxonomy-terms, blocks

I have a single page that is rendering an additional menu_block that repeats my sub-navigation link (which are displayed in a side column). I have a Primary Link in the main navigation that has two sub pages: Teacher Resources and Instructional Materials. Teacher Resources works as expected (menu_block output is empty), but when Instructional Materials is selected, it outputs AN ADDITIONAL menu_block duplicating the sub-navigation links.

[image: screenshot]

These two pages use taxonomy terms, which I'm not too familiar with. I've compared each of these pages in the various menu and taxonomy settings, and the configurations look to be the same. Any Suggestions as to where to look next?

I'm using Drupal 6.16 and a theme based on Zen 6.x-1.1.

Comment: First check to see if there are two blocks in the sidebar. If so deactivate one and check the result. The other place to check is the theme configuration. If you have a menu activated for a region defined in the theme, and a block activated to show the same menu, then you will see two copies.

Comment: Triskelion, thanks for the response. There was another menu block in the side bar that was rendering for that page only. Thanks again for your help!